# How to transact in batches in camel

Tags: spring, csv, neo4j, apache-camel

I am doing some ETL that process some input CSV files and load then to Neo4j using Spring data Neo4j.
I have 2 routes one that takes the input CSV split by line and send to the second route that does the load line by line in transnational mode.

The following is the first route

---

```
@Override
void configure() throws Exception {
    from(endpoint)
            .id('CSV_ROUTE')
            .unmarshal(buildCsvDataFormat())
            .split(body())
            .streaming()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .recipientList(header('IMPORTER_ROUTE'))
```

---

And the following is the second route

---

```
@Override
void configure() throws Exception {
    from(endpoint)
            .transacted()
            .id(routeId)
            .bean(importer)
}
```

---

How can I make transaction to commit in batches for example of 10 lines instead of every line ?

Thank you
 Luis Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. Transactions is per message in Camel.

Also mind transaction is not some magic fairy dust you can turn on and then anything you touch becomes transactional.

In Java transactions often only work with transactional resources such as JDBC and JMS.